# How to CURL -H basic auth in R to access API

Tags: r, curl, libcurl

I want to retrieve data from a classifier API. The documentation showed me:

```
curl -H "Authentication: Basic <my_secret>" "http://www.superapi.io/classifier/test
model_id=123&value=your+text"
```

How do I implement this in R? I tried with package RCurl:

```
getURL("http://www.superapi.io/classifier/test",
userpwd ="secret",
httpheader=list(model_id="123",value="your+text"))
```

but this was didnt work:

```
[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>405 Method Not
Allowed</title>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The method is not allowed for the requested
URL </p>\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

answer:

```
getURL("http://wwww.superapi.io/classifier/test?_model_id=123&value=TEST", userpwd="<secret>",
httpauth = 1L)
```

Comment: some clarification would be really helpful.